# How to put an icon inside an input placeholder in html?

Tags: html, css

Been stuck for an hour and questions here in Stack Overflow about this topic seems to be outdated

Comment: Hi Rookie, welcome at SO! If you want ppl at SO to help you out, you will need to post a [reprex] of the work you have done sofar to solve your problem. Also, check this answer: [SO11757196](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757196/image-in-placeholder-html)

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand you correctly.

```css
.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_edit{
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://www.pinpng.com/pngs/m/290-2908373_instagram-search-icon-gray-small-search-icon-png.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #878787;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 30px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 45px 0 20px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_edit" placeholder="text for search">
```